# What's wrong in my example about Q-matrix?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I find the next property about Q-matrices:
$$ \text{Let Q a Q-Matrix, then}
\frac{d^k P(0)}{dt^k}=Q^k
 ; \text{ for }  k=0,1,2,\cdots.$$ I was trying to verify the property with the next example:
$Q=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ then
$$P(s)=\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-s} & e^s \\
e^s & e^{-s}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$\frac{d^k P(0)}{ds^k}=\begin{pmatrix}
(-1)^ke^{-0} & e^0 \\
e^0 & (-1)^ke^{-0}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
(-1)^k & 1 \\
1 & (-1)^k
\end{pmatrix}\neq Q^k$$
But it contradicts the proposition!! I want to know what is wrong in my example or interpretation.

Comment: "What is wrong" is, first, that your $P(t)$ is not the correct matrix (it is not even a transition matrix). Solving $$P(t)=e^{tQ}$$ yields $$P(t)=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1+e^{-2t}&1-e^{-2t}\\1-e^{-2t}&1+e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}$$ (What is *also* wrong is that $Q^k$ is not the matrix you write.)

Comment: If I want to find the P(t) matriz, Always is neccesary solve the backward or forward equations or  there is other way?

Comment: Well, in the present case, the expansion $$P(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}Q^n$$ works like a charm since each $Q^n$ can be readily identified, hence, yes, there can be "(some) other way(s)".

Answer (score -1):

If $P(s)$ and $Q$ are as above, then we have

$\frac{d^k P(0)}{ds^k}=Q^k$ only for $k=1,3,5,...$.

Comment: Why is my answer not useful ??

Comment: The question asks "what is wrong in (the OP's) example or interpretation". Where do you address this concern?